# Getting VPN client to access the Internet only through VPN

Tags: vpn, routing

I am using raspberry as an OpenVPN client to connect to other networks. My routing table on that machine is:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ip route list
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 202
10.1.0.0/24 via 10.1.0.1 dev tun0
10.1.0.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.0.30
10.10.10.0/24 via 10.1.0.1 dev tun0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.101  metric 202
192.168.88.0/24 via 10.1.0.1 dev tun0
```

Everything works fine, but I would like raspberry to access the internet ONLY through VPN, but in the same time I still want it to be accessible from LAN (192.168.1.0/24). I don't want to use "redirect-gateway def1" in config, as it "disappears from LAN".
How can I achieve that?

Comment: two network interfaces?

Comment: What hinders you to use a firewall like `ufw` (based on iptables)?

Comment: @jiggunjer only 1 physical interface. ifconfig gives: 

eth0 (192.168.1.101), lo (127.0.0.1), tun0 (10.1.0.30)

Comment: @GiantTree you suggest to use ufw? Never tried, so I don't know that too.

Comment: `ufw` is simply a front-end to `iptables`. I use it to block all outgoing traffic that doesn't go through a VPN (tun0) unless is comes or goes to my local network. It's not too complicated to setup (`ufw` is an abbreviation of "uncomplicated firewall" for a reason).